# What is Blockchain ? What is Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain

The question title at this point in time is really frustrating. But the background of asking this question is:

I am completely new to Blockchain and wanted to know how Blockchain and Ethereum relate to each other?

The more I google about **What is Blockchain**, I get the same demonstration like:

1. What does a block contains
2. How blocks are linked by hash
3. How it is secured
4. How it is compared to Mysql and so on

What I wanted to figure out is:

- If Blockchain is a set of tools that I need to set up in my server so that I can use this blockchain to create Apps. More simply: Is Blockchain a set of downloadable and installable tools? How can I create my own Blockchain in my local environment?
- Is Blockchain actually a concept/Specification something like RFC so that it is implemented by different software projects like Ethereum or Hyperledger?

The definition of Ethereum is more confusing for a beginner.
I found myriads of different definitions on the web. For example:

- Ethereum is a blockchain
- Ethereum is a blockchain protocol
- Ethereum is a framework
- Ethereum is an OS

I don't know how to fit them altogether to get a solid definition. I just want to be clear about which stands where and with which definition?

I think this question and answers that will be provided here will help lots of people to remove their confusion

Comment: Much work has been put into https://ethereum.org  Have you tried it? For example https://ethereum.org/en/what-is-ethereum  You can also provide feedback at https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org-website/issues

Answer (score 0):

> Is Blockchain a set of downloadable and installable tools? How can I
> create my own Blockchain in my local environment?

Blockchain is a technology, you have different kind of blockchain, namely Bitcoin, Ethereum, Hyperledger, Solana, Fantom, Polygon, etc. to name a few.

To connect to a blockchain you can connect to a Remote Procedure Call (RPC) it is a kind of API that allows developers to communicate to a server (node). Once you are connected to a RPC Node, you can query, read blockchain data, submit transactions, etc.

You have different frameworks, the most popular are **Hardhat** and **Truffle**, they allow you to deploy your contract on a **EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine)**, to simulate transactions on a local blockchain that reproduces the same conditions as a mainnet. It comes with a set of tools to test your smart contract.

> Is Blockchain actually a concept/Specification something like RFC so
> that it is implemented by different software projects like Ethereum or
> Hyperledger?

You have different blockchain, is like with DB you have SQL, NoSQL but they're all different, different usecases, different way of doing, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am still struggling to understand how the blockchain is created? Which part of the system creates it? Is it for example the Ethereum that creates the blockchain and stores it in the filesystem? As far I  can guess, in a Dapp, the lowest layer of it is Blockchain similar to Data Link Layer in a OSI model. Is there this  kind of layering information somewhere? Any link/URL would be a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

The `link` below can give you a little more clarity on how decentralized applications are created. And can give you a deeper understanding of Ethereum and details on how to get started when making a blockchain application.

The first thing to note is that a blockchain application has a frontend and a backend. The frontend is typically written in HTML and makes up the user interface of the application. The backend is the part that remains on the Ethereum network and connects with the frontend to provide its necessary function.

Since you are looking into Ethereum, I would suggest that you also think about smart contracts. Ethereum is a decentralized blockchain platform that establishes a peer-to-peer network securely through smart contracts. Smart Contracts allow different people to make transactions without the need for a third party. For example, it is able to disburse payment once the other user has held up their end of the bargain.

([https://www.blockchain-council.org/blockchain/how-to-architect-a-blockchain-application/#:~:text=The%20backend%20is%20built%20using,C%2B%2B%20with%20some%20JS%20concepts](https://www.blockchain-council.org/blockchain/how-to-architect-a-blockchain-application/#:%7E:text=The%20backend%20is%20built%20using,C%2B%2B%20with%20some%20JS%20concepts)).)